# Trying to load a .dat file into python and reading the file

Tags: python

```
data=[]
time=[]
with open('fismflux20010415.dat','r') as info:
 for i in info:
    data.append(i)
time.append(data[1:5])
if __name__=="__main__":
   print(time)
```

I need help trying to load a .dat file into python and put the data into 2 different lists. The way that the file is set up is there is a date followed by 59 data points (ex: 2001 4 15 0 0 0 than 59 data points) and I would like to put the date in a list and then the 59 data points in another. So, they will be at the same index but in different lists. This is what I have so far.

Comment: What did you try before post this question ?

Comment: Can you at least put some code up for us to look at? Also what does the data look like? We can't help ya if you don't give us details and if you don't bother to post your code.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: 2001       4      15       0       0       0   0.00389146   0.00235569
   0.00127807  0.000907945  0.000652733  0.000373057  0.000250119  0.000194776
  0.000389740  0.000132412   0.00794561   0.00765861  0.000155069  9.98118e-05
  0.000107400  0.000238970  9.09176e-05  0.000107256  0.000176666  0.000125050
  0.000139768  0.000160256  8.20643e-05  6.09152e-05  1.66361e-05  1.32056e-05
  1.33021e-05  2.54237e-05  1.01860e-05  2.17750e-05  0.000100757  3.26597e-05
  1.89702e-05  9.86262e-05  4.17277e-05  3.83911e-05  4.89190e-05  5.85547e-05
  1.30602e-05  3.76383e-05  0.000141262

Comment: This is what the data looks like but there are 59 points and then the data repeats in this format for multiple times.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to include that data. As you can see, the comments destroy the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in info:
    parts = line.split()
    data.append(parts[6:])
    time.append(data[:6])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the stuff:

```
data=[]
time=[]

f = open( 'fismflux20010415.dat' )
f_lines = f.readlines()

for l in f_lines:
    tmp_l = l.split()
    time.append( [ int( i ) for i in tmp_l[ : 6 ] ] )
    data.append( [ float( i ) for i in tmp_l[ 6 : ] ] )

if __name__=="__main__":
   print(time)
   print(data)
```